# add +1 to a column with condition in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, addition

I have a dataframe called barometre2013 with a column called q0qc that contain this numbers:

```
[1] 15  1  9 15 9  3  6  3  3  6  6 10 15  6 15 10
```

I want to add +1 to the numbers that are >= 10, so the result should be this:

```
[1] 16  1  9 16 9  3  6  3  3  6  6 11 16  6 16 11
```

I have tried this code:

```
if (barometre2013$q0qc > 9) {
  barometre2013$q0qc <- barometre2013$q0qc + 1
}
```

But this add +1 to all the numbers without respecting the condition:

```
[1] 16  2  10 16 10  4  7  4  4  7  7 11 16  7 16 11
```

How can I do what I want ?

Thank a lot.

Comment: `barometre2013$q0qc <- barometre2013$q0qc + (barometre2013$q0qc >= 10)`

Comment: alternative: `barometre2013$q0qc[barometre2013$q0qc>=10] <- barometre2013$q0qc+1`

Comment: `ifelse` is the vectorized version of `if`. The other comments are efficient and fancy, but the basic way would be `barometre2013$q0qc <- barometre2013$q0qc + ifelse(barometre2013$q0qc >= 10, 1, 0)`

Comment: @Jilber, that code won't work. You mean `b2$q[b2$q >= 10] <- b2$q[b2$q >= 10] + 1` (variable names abbreviated)

Comment: @Gregor, I don't think @Jilber's code is fancy. It's the simplest basic way of conditionally altering a vector. New R users should grok this before using `ifelse`.

Comment: @dash2 you're right! I forgot index rhs

Answer (score 2):

When you executed:

```
if (barometre2013$q0qc > 9) {
  barometre2013$q0qc <- barometre2013$q0qc + 1
}
```

... you should have seen a warning about "only the first value being evaluated". That first value in `barometre2013$q0qc` was 15 and since it was TRUE, then that assignment was done on the entire vector. `ifelse` or Boolean logic are approaches suggested in the comments for conditional evaluation and/or assignment. The first:

```
barometre2013$q0qc <- barometre2013$q0qc + (barometre2013$q0qc >= 10)
```

... added a vector of 1 and 0's to the starting vector; 1 if the logical expression is satisfied and 0 if not. If you wanted to add something other than one (which is the numeric value of TRUE) you could have multiplied that second term by the desired increment or decrement.

Another approach was to use `ifelse` which does do a conditional test of its first argument on returns either the second or third argument on an item-by-item basis:

```
barometre2013$q0qc <- barometre2013$q0qc + ifelse(barometre2013$q0qc >= 10, 1, 0)
```

The third approach suggested by dash2 would be to only modify those values that meet the condition. Note that this method requires having the "test vector on both sides of the assignment (which is why dash2 was correcting the earlier comment:

```
barometre2013$q0qc[barometre2013$q0qc>=10] <- 
                      barometre2013$q0qc[barometre2013$q0qc>=10]+ 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation !

Comment: Sometimes it's useful to know what went wrong so you can better remember what _not_ to do in the future. Remember to pay attention to the text of warning messages.

Comment: Btw I choose to do the third approach ;)

Comment: I'm sorry to do that, but I am really desperate. Do you think you can answer my other question? I really need help. Please!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50178993/tolower-function-and-merging-two-dataframes

Answer (score -6):

```
    data <- c(15,1,9,15,9,3,6,3,3,6,6,10,15,6,15,10)

    data2 <- 

    as.numeric( 
      for(i in data){
      if(i >= 10){ i = i +1 }
      print(i)
      }
    )

class(data)
class(data2)
```

Comment: it is really not what you should do, I am sorry to say. Your object `data2` will be empty because you are not assigning anything, and you should really consider vectorised operation in R. So it is wrong and doesnt' answer the question

Comment: I can consider whatever I want :- ) in this free world!  haha  maybe it will teach him loops at the same time :- )

Comment: object is not empty, same class as started with, gives correct answer, I realize that Vector is the right way to go, but that wasn't specified in the question, maybe it will teach him other things too and get the right answers, so there...